# How do I detect the KeyboardEvent for the escape key?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, console.log

Whether the fact that a lot of features have been deprecated or are not part of the current standard for the **KeyboardEvent** object class. Was just wondering why whenever I press either **shift** or **esc**. Non of the keys show up on my console for Chrome or Mozilla.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(e.key);
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.shiftKey);
});
```

Browser Consoles used

- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
- [Web Inspector] 
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: The `keypress` event does not trigger for each key, only when it corresponds to a character (or backspace). Use `keydown` or `keyup` instead.

Answer (score 9):

`keypress` is only triggered when a printable character is pressed. For all keys, you need to work with `keyup` or `keydown`.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)**:

> **keypress**
>
> The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value
>   is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are
>   alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys. Examples of keys that don't
>   produce a character value are modifier keys such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Meta</kbd>.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(e.key);
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.shiftKey);
});
```

```html
<h1>Click into this area and then press ESC</h1>
```